# Вывести сообщение успешной отправки формы и сделать редирект. PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно при отправке форме вывести сообщение на 3 секунды и сделать редирект без js на php, почему то не происходит редирект, вот обработчик формы

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$question = $_POST['question'];
$date = date("d/m/Y");

$add = $wpdb->insert('wp_qns', array('user_name' => $name, 'mail' => $mail, 'question' => $question, 'date' => $date), array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'));

echo "Спасибо за обращение, Ваш вопрос отправлен и будет опубликован после модерации";

sleep(3);

wp_mail( 'info@t.ru', 'Новый вопрос!', '<span>Вам задали вопрос.<br>' .$question. '</span>');
wp_redirect('https://domen.ru/');
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы понять, почему так не работает, нужно знать три вещи:

- невозможно отправлять заголовки после отправки тела ответа
- ответ отправляется не сразу, а попадает в буферы - [PHP имеет буфер](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering), а также веб-сервер обычно также буферизирует данные, отправляя "все сразу" (буфер Nginx [4-8 Кб](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering))
- заголовок `Location` принимается браузером на исполнение сразу, без всяких пауз и выводов сообщений

Итак, разберемся.

### Что такое функция wp_redirect

Функция `wp_redirect();` отправляет `Location` - [заголовок о редиректе](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/0e3147c40e91f6eb1f57585724be173e3c04a719/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1246). Браузер видит заголовок и сразу переходит. Что находится в самом ответе сервера, он не показывает (`echo ...` не будет выводиться в браузере).

Однако, любые заголовки невозможно отправить после отправки тела ответа. Поэтому заголовок `Location` PHP просто не отправляет, и об этом выводятся предупреждения, но у вас похоже, включено подавление ошибок.

Как включить вывод ошибок:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Выведется:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...
```

Вот структура HTTP ответа, чтобы вы представляли:

```
заголовки (wp_redirect())
(пуста строка)
тело ответа (echo ...)
```

Поэтому сделать `echo` перед `wp_redirect()` нельзя. Ну, на самом деле можно, PHP обычно [еще немного кеширует ответ](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) и все-таки позволяет "вклинить" заголовки, хотя уже начал писать ответ. Как посмотреть: `die(ini_get("output_buffering"));`

### Буфер веб-сервера

Но то, что вы хотите - показ сообщения, пауза, отправка почты, редирект - так работать не будет, потому что веб-сервер кеширует данные ответа, и отправляет большими кусками, 4-8 Кб в случае Nginx, в вашем случае - сразу одним куском. Поэтому все что происходит в промежутке `echo ... sleep` не будет с паузой отправлено в браузер, а попадет в буфер веб-сервера, и сразу будет отправлено по завершении скрипта. И без заголовка Location, как вы уже поняли. Но задержка в 3 секунды будет.

## Решение

На самом деле, нужно просто воспользоваться другой возможностью. Отправьте в виде ответа HTML с тегом `<meta http-equiv="refresh"`, вот пример редиректа в гугл через 3 секунды.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.google.com/" />
```

## PS

В самом PHP-скрипте также может быть `ob_start()` (я не знаю, делает это Wordpress или нет), и тогда используется [собственный буфер PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php).

Вот грубый способ выключить буфер и скинуть все данные в браузер:

```
// Отключаем буферизацию вывода (2)
while (ob_get_level()) {
  ob_end_flush();
}
```